# Crate a canvas & JS game based on Mario but using prompts

Tags: javascript, canvas

I am working on a project where a figurine is jumping, and at the moment of the jump on a platform, it will stop.

```
platforms.forEach((platform) => {
    if (
      player.position.y + player.height <= platform.position.y &&
      player.position.y + player.height + player.velocity.y >=
        platform.position.y &&
      player.position.x + player.width >= platform.position.x &&
      player.position.x <= platform.position.x + platform.width
    ) {
      player.velocity.y = 0;
    }
  });
```

To define different platforms, I used an array.

My question is, how can I make a pop-up window with a message when a player. velocity.y = 0;
And after it happens, the window will close, and the movement starts again

Also, the first two elements of the array should be excluded because they create the running platform.

This is the code I try to use, but after the window is open, it will open again and again.

```
{
  let guess = Number(
    window.prompt(
      "Please solve the problem: " + randomNumber1 + "+" + randomNumber2
    )
  );
  if (guess != sum) {
    let randomNumber1 = Math.floor(Math.random() * 10 + 1);
    let randomNumber2 = Math.floor(Math.random() * 10 + 1);
    let sum = randomNumber1 + randomNumber2;

    alert("Try again!");
    let guess = Number(
      window.prompt(
        "Please solve the problem: " + randomNumber1 + "+" + randomNumber2
      )
    );
  } else {
    alert("Good Job!!");
  }
}
```

Comment: I don't understand your second code - you display `randomNumber1 + "+" + randomNumber2` before you even generate random numbers. You should first generate numbers, calculate sum and later run loop which asks for guess. And if you want to repeat it then you should use `while` instead of `if`.  And you should generate numbers before `while`

Comment: the code you show is incomplete ... how does the first code block relates to the second? _ _ _ if you need to skip elements in a loop, better do a for and you can set the starting point on what you need, something like this: `for (let i = 2; i < array.length; i++) {`

Comment: in other languages and libraries which use event loop I would use boolean variable `pause = True` and inside event loop I would use this value (with `if/else`) to check if elements should move or they should stay in place.